# What causes this characteristic pattern and what is it called?

Tags: extrusion, flashforge-creator

I am using a Qidi Tech 1 (Flashforge Creator Pro). There is no auto bed leveling and I have done my best to tweak it by hand using the screws underneath the heated bed plate.

What is causing this characteristic pattern? This while printing the first layer of some test pattern. I don't know what the end result is supposed to look like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These "stretch marks" are typically the result of a nozzle that is a little too close to the build surface. Next time levelling be sure to use a thicker piece of paper or allow for less drag when moving the the paper between nozzle and bed.